# Where is “stretch” (UV) in Blender 2.8?

Tags: uv

Where is “stretch” (UV) in the last version of Blender 2.8? In earlier version Stretch was in Display, but now Stretch is absent:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

In Blender 2.9 it is on the overlays menu:

[image: Display Stretch location]

Answer (score 6):

It's in *Display > Overlays > Stretching*.

[image]

Comment: Ow, thank you!!

Comment: For future reference, this appears to have been removed. I assume this was to consolidate tool options so they were not in multiple places. It is only in the Overlays drop down menu in the UV window as specified in the other reply.

Comment: @ChrisLee That is correct. This answer was written for a 2.8x version.